# How to implement batch delete?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

Currently I get a list of items with url api/item and I can only delete an item by sending a delete request to each of items' urls like: `api/item/52` and `api/item/53`.

Obviously it isn't wise to send 50 requests to delete 50 items so I'm wondering how can I implement a batch delete using django rest framework.

Answer (score 1):

The best you're going to reliably get is

```
DELETE /api/item?id=52,53
```

You can try putting a message body into your DELETE request, but many frameworks and containers will misbehave if you do so. This is because the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) is unclear on whether DELETE requests support a message body.

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary "to be deleted" item collection resource first:

```
POST /api/collections/items
```

Passing in a payload like this (assuming JSON):

```
{
   "items" : ["/api/item/52", "/api/item/53"]
}
```

Which would return a URI like this in the `Location` response header, representing the set of items that the new collection references:

```
/api/collections/items/7266447
```

You can then issue a single DELETE on the collection URI and it will nuke all the referenced elements:

```
DELETE /api/collections/items/7266447
```